# VBA Loop Over Several Directories and Merge Data in Summary Workbook

Tags: excel, merge, summary

I have a macro that runs over a specified directory, creates a new summary workbook, and then copies selected data from all the excel files present (in the defined directory) into that summary workbook, it then saves the summary workbook into a new defined location and closes. I am obliged to change the directory name each time I have multiple folders for data merging, and sometimes over 30 directories.

I want this macro to loop automatically over several directories contained inside one root directory and perform the same operation detailed above. How can it be possible? I used the "scripting folder" method but it returned error when I ran the code...never got it worked!

Secondly, I want this macro to save the summary workbook with its folder name, the directory from which data is merged.

My code is here, please take a look and propose me a solution:

```
Sub MergeSitu()
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceCcount As Long, FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange1 As Range, destrange1 As Range
Dim sourceRange2 As Range, destrange2 As Range
Dim sourceRange3 As Range, destrange3 As Range
Dim Rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
Dim Cnum As Long
Dim listwb As Workbook
Dim mMonth As Range

 ' Change this to the path\folder location of the files.
MyPath = "D:\data\19h\13 feb\"

' Add a slash at the end of path if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If
' Fill in the myFiles array with the list of Excel files in
' the search folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

' Change the application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
With Application

'--> Set contractor list file
Set listwb = .Workbooks.Open _
("D:\data\DataAssemble.xlsx")
End With
Set BaseWks = listwb.Sheets(1)
Cnum = 1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
Range("P1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Prod"

For Each mMonth In Sheets(1).Range("P1")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)
 ActiveSheet.Name = mMonth
Next
Set BaseWks = listwb.Sheets(7)
Cnum = 1

' Loop through all of the files in the myFiles array.
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

            On Error Resume Next
            Set sourceRange1 = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B1420")

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange1 = Nothing

            Else
                ' If the source range uses all of the rows
                ' then skip this file.
                If sourceRange1.Rows.count >= BaseWks.Rows.count Then
                    Set sourceRange1 = Nothing

                End If
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange1 Is Nothing Then

                SourceCcount = sourceRange1.Columns.count

                If Cnum + SourceCcount >= BaseWks.Columns.count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough columns in the sheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Copy the file name in the first row.
                    With sourceRange1
                        BaseWks.Cells(1, Cnum). _
                                Resize(, .Columns.count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                    End With


                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange1 = BaseWks.Cells(1, Cnum)
                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange1
                        Set destrange1 = destrange1. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.count, .Columns.count)
                    End With

                    destrange1.Value = sourceRange1.Value

                    Cnum = Cnum + SourceCcount
                End If
            End If
        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    Next FNum
End If
listwb.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\data\Merged\19h\Data_ " & (FolderName) & ".xlsx",  
Password:="", _  
WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

ExitTheSub:
'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!
Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

I obtained this code from: http://vba-tutorial.com/merging-multiple-workbooks-togeather-by-searching-directories-and-sub-folders/

Step 1 - The recursive function

```
Sub RecursiveFileSearch(ByVal targetFolder As String, ByRef objRegExp As Object, _
                ByRef matchedFiles As Collection, ByRef objFSO As Object)

    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objSubFolders As Object

    'Get the folder object associated with the target directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(targetFolder)

    'Loop through the files current folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then
            matchedFiles.Add (objFile)
        End If
    Next

    'Loop through the each of the sub folders recursively
    Set objSubFolders = objFolder.Subfolders
    For Each objSubfolder In objSubFolders
        RecursiveFileSearch objSubfolder, objRegExp, matchedFiles, objFSO
    Next

    'Garbage Collection
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objSubFolders = Nothing

End Sub
```

Step 2 - Recursive controller

```
Function FindPatternMatchedFiles(sPath As String) As Collection

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegExp.Pattern = ".*\.(xls|xlsx)"
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Set colFiles = New Collection

    RecursiveFileSearch sPath, objRegExp, colFiles, objFSO

    'Garbage Collection
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objRegExp = Nothing

    Set FindPatternMatchedFiles = colFiles

End Function
```

Step 3 - Merge together each of the matched Workbooks

```
Sub MergeWorkbooks(sPath As String, sWbName As String)

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Set colFiles = FindPatternMatchedFiles(sPath)

    Dim appExcel As New Excel.Application
    appExcel.Visible = False

    Dim wbDest As Excel.Workbook
    Set wbDest = appExcel.Workbooks.Add()

    Dim wbToAdd As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    For Each file In colFiles

        Set wbToAdd = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(file)

        For Each sheet In wbToAdd.Sheets
            sheet.Copy Before:=wbDest.Sheets(wbDest.Sheets.Count)
        Next sheet

        wbToAdd.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Next

    wbDest.Close True, sPath + "\" + sWbName
    Set wbDest = Nothing
    Set appExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Step 4 - Call the Merge Workbooks sub routine

```
Sub Main()

    MergeWorkbooks "C:\Path\To\Folder", "Awesomeness.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: please answer the question

Comment: I just updated my answer with a complete code solution.  Sorry, it was my first post and I'm still trying to figure out how all this works.

Comment: well welcome, this is why we go through all first post's. welcome to SO, i joined only about a month ago, but this is awesome, will take 3-4 posts to get the hang of it though.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight, now that I've fixed the response are you able to remove the -1?